# How to turn off wrapping in a grid in UWP XAML?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I need a template where the wrapping of the grid items should be turned off and list them vertically (as a listview control would) and stretch the items to the whole width of the page. How do I turn off wrapping of the grid without fixing the width of the items.

Thanks,
Soorya

Comment: I don't understand. Replace your GridView with a ListView, and set the property HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch. What I am missing?

Comment: Basically we have two templates and one of the templates needs the control to wrap it and the other template should not. I can use a listview and gridview and toggle them. But i want to use only one control and change the template instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want wrapping, then don't use a WrapGrid anymore. Change the ItemsPanel in your GridView to `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />`. Best of luck!

Comment: Wouldn't `VirtualizingStackPanel` be an even better choice in case of a larger number of items?